# How can I open an external browser window and refresh it inside a VB.net application?

Tags: vb.net

We have an existing VB.net application.  Upon an event, we need to open a browser window.  I'm able to open the browser window like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://s3web01/suggestions?item=" + strItem + "&co=" + strOrder)
```

Upon another event, we need to refresh the browser window with different parameters for strItem and strOrder.

If I call the same code above, it opens a new tab in the browser window.  Is there any way to refresh the same browser window that was previously opened?

Comment: The tabbed interface isn't exposed at all in the automation interfaces.  A workaround is to use WebBrowser in a Winforms or WPF app, you can readily control it with its Navigate() method.  Nice for the user too, no window juggling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a reference to the following COM libraries:  `Microsoft Internet Controls` (namespace ShDocVw), and `Microsoft HTML Object Library` (namespace mshtml).

Then you can create a new IE instance:

```
Dim IE As ShDocVw.InternetExplorer = New ShDocVw.InternetExplorer
```

and control it like so:  `IE.Navigate("http://blah.com")`

refresh it like so:  `IE.Refresh`

etc